# want to open USB port using java

Tags: java, microcontroller

i need to send and receive data to/from a microcontroller using java using usb 
i connect the micro to the Pc unig usb to serial cable and need to pass data to the micro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://sourceforge.net/projects/javax-usb/

I suspect it will not be plain sailing for you. Grab that library, try to write some USB interactions. I did it once a long time ago [[code]](https://github.com/Synesso/Monci/blob/master/src/main/java/au/com/loftinspace/usblight/delcom/LightImpl.java) and the hardest part was figuring out what bytes I needed to send down the cable.

Come back here with some fully-formed questions (with code samples and error messages where appropriate) when you have any problems you can't solve yourself.

Comment: thanks mate but i'm new to java and new to this website